# Trying to take a variable's value and make it the name of another variable. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, var

I'm trying to take a function's input (objectName) and make that value create a variable. So if objectName = "abcd" I would want the variable to be created be abcd. Is there a way I can do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `window[variableName]` like this:

```
//Variable name
var name = "abc";

//window[name] is equal to the variable abc
window[name] = 123;

//show 123
alert(abc);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7GSW/)

Comment: If you are using JQuery, the command window.name will create a global property of the window. This can be manipulated the same way a variable can. You would reference it with window.abc but, I like Shyrmes way a little bit better :D

Comment: Wow that was pretty simple haha. Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm in my function.